# Single item generation with build_fa / plot_fa (IMak package in R)

Tags: r

My goal is to transfer a questionnaire from one survey software to another. The questionnaire consists of 30 tasks that include figural analogies:

[image: figural analogies]

To this end, I need to insert each of the answer items into the survey, individually, thereby creating 8 multiple choice options (and 2 options that only include text). However, the tasks that were generated using the IMak package in R are only available to me as units, containing all 8 answer items (see image). If I understand correctly, the functions build_fa and plot_fa don't allow users to generate single images of each answer item but only entire "sheets", containing both the question items and the answer items. For example, I used the code below to generate the above image.

```r
one <- build_fa(isomorphs = 1, dot.mov = c(1, 2), correct = 1)

dir <- "C:/Users/os22e836/Desktop/REDCaps"

## Plot them:
plot_fa(one, directory = dir)
```

Is there a way to generate each answer item individually, as a `.png` or `.jpg`? I assume R creates single items and then arranges them in a grid. My goal is to generate all items individually, so I don't have to cut them by hand from the above image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's an example about that in the plot_fa instructions, they use:

```
plot_fa(something, mode = "C")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "mode" argument of plot_fa. The C mode plots every single image. I've seen this done by some researchers.